# I am having an async issue with goOffline() for Fiebase RTDB using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have this script that need to be ran using forever.js . I am using firebase and for some reason when we get to the end of the script Firebase tends to stay online. Due to JS not processing code block by block, I can't just use `db.goOffline()` without using async . My implementation may be a bit off.

Here is my code

```
const https = require('node:https');


var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("...");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "..."
});

var db = admin.database();


const moment = require("moment");

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

arr = new Array();
id_Arr = new Array();

race_arr = new Array();
tl_arr = new Array();




const getLiveRaces = async () => {

    for(let m=0; m <= id_Arr.length -1; m++){
  await delay(100);

// Get Timeline

 https.get('https://apilink'+id_Arr[m]+'/apikey', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let raw = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { raw += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedDa = JSON.parse(raw);
     tl_arr.push(parsedDa);
     console.log(tl_arr);

     var lines = db.ref("timeline");
const linesRef = lines.child(id_Arr[m]);


linesRef.set([tl_arr[0]]);


    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
tl_arr.splice(0, race_arr.length);

  }

}


const offload = async () => {
await getLiveRaces();

db.goOffline();
}



const delayed = async () => {
  await moment(nextRace).subtract(3, 'minutes').fromNow();

}



https.get('https://linkto-api', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
      arr.push(parsedData.sport_events);
      var xm = arr[0].filter(function(item){
  return item.status == 'not_started';
});

      for(i = 0; i  <= xm.length -1; i++){
        id_Arr.unshift(xm[i].id);
      }

console.log(id_Arr);
if(id_Arr.length > 0){
getLiveRaces();

}
else if(id_Arr.length == 0){
        var xm2 = arr[0].filter(function(item){
  return item.status == 'not_started';
});

nextRace = xm2[0].scheduled;

  Delay
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(i); }, i * 1000);
}

}

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

How can I ensure that when the function `getLiveRaces();` gets ran and only after that Firebase disconnects, so the script closes and `forever.js` could start the script all over .